# Obtaining the data from a Renko chart

Tags: finance

How can I obtain the data of the trace of a `RenkoChart`? Any code available?

Something like obtaining the range of dates or the middle point of the box.

Comment: What is a renkochart?

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{{2010, 1, 4}, 130.54}, {{2010, 1, 5}, 128.96}, {{2010, 1, 6}, 128.13}, 
      {{2010, 1, 7}, 127.68} , {{2010, 1, 8}, 128.96}, {{2010, 1, 11}, 127.61}, 
      {{2010, 1, 12}, 128.63}, {{2010, 1, 13}, 128.35}, {{2010, 1, 14}, 130.4}, 
      {{2010, 1, 15}, 129.88}, {{2010, 1, 19}, 132.21}, {{2010, 1, 20}, 128.37}} ;

rc = RenkoChart[data, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
pts = Cases[rc, Rectangle[a_, b_, ___] :> Mean[{a, b}], ∞]; 
Show[rc, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point @ pts}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can extract the tooltips which contain the information on dates and values:

```
DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[ RenkoChart[data], Tooltip[_,  t_] :> 
 ({DateList[#], ToExpression @ #2} & @@@
  Partition[DeleteCases[StringSplit @ t[[1]], "~"],  2]), ∞]
```

> {{{{2010, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 130.54}, {{2010, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 128.96}},
>    {{{2010, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 128.13}}, {{{2010, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.},  127.68}},
>    {{{2010, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, 128.96}, {{2010, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.},   130.4}},
>    {{{2010, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 129.88}, {{2010, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.},  132.21}},
>    {{{2010, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0.}, 128.37}}}

Comment: Excelent answer. I was no able to do it. Thanks

Comment: If you change the PerformanceGoal -> "Speed" by a brick size or  quality It is not working? why?

Comment: @roble_the reason for using `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` to prevent `RenkoChart` from creating `Tooltip`s (and dynamic elements) so that post-processing the output to extract elements is easier.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and help. But if I want the pair {middle date, midle point} of ^SP500 index. I can not do it. The first code give me the midle data but the second give a dates that not correspond. How Will be the code for the ^SP500 index that prodeuce pairs of mean of (date, data) of each renko box ?

Comment: DeleteDuplicates@
 Cases[RenkoChart["^SP500"], 
  Tooltip[_, 
    t_] :> ({DateList[#], ToExpression@#2} & @@@ 
     Partition[DeleteCases[StringSplit@t[[1]], "~"], 2]), \[Infinity]] produces 23 points

Comment: rcsp = RenkoChart["^SP500", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
ptssp = Cases[rcsp, 
   Rectangle[a_, b_, ___] :> Mean[{a, b}], \[Infinity]]; produces 16 points

Comment: @roble_t, if you remove `DeleteDuplicates` both methods give 23 points.

Comment: but not the same points due to one has "speed" and the other no